# Glassfish - Marking servlet FacesServlet as unavailable

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, application-server, facesservlet

When I startup my Glassfish 2.1 server, it seems to startup without problems, but when I try to access its Admin console I get the error:

```
The requested resource (Servlet FacesServlet is not available) is not available.
```

On its console and server.log, this is what I can see:

```
[#|2013-05-09T14:59:36.647+0200|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Application server startup complete.|#]

[#|2013-05-09T15:01:23.250+0200|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config|_ThreadID=15;_ThreadName=httpWorkerThread-4848-0;;|Initializing Mojarra (1.2_13-b01-FCS) for context ''|#]

[#|2013-05-09T15:01:24.420+0200|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web|_ThreadID=15;_ThreadName=httpWorkerThread-4848-0;|PWC1412: WebModule[] ServletContext.log():PWC1409: Marking servlet FacesServlet as unavailable|#]
```

The last 2 entries are logged when I access the Admin console for the first time.

Why is glassfish marking FacesServlet as unavailable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Richfaces jars in my **glassfish_home/lib/ext** directory that were somehow causing this problem.

If I remove them I'm able to use the Admin console again.

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to this bug:

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-14329

... which was fixed on on version 3.1.